Host disk access from privileged docker container on macOS
I ran a privileged container on macOS with this command:
docker run -it --privileged alpine sh

It runs with no error.
I need to access the macOS host disk from the container. How can I do that?

Your docker daemon, and the containers it starts are themselves running in a VM.

Thanks and is there a way to mount this VM disk, in order to access other containers ?

You changed your goal from "access the Mac disk" to "access the VM disk" and I don't know why. Looks like an XY problem.

In fact i want to access to the top hosting mechanism. @A.B said containers are running in a VM. So I want to access this VM first

I think it's probably better to describe what you want to achieve. Why do you want to access the disk? Will a volume suffice?

I want to understand how it works and i want to understand consequences if a user creates a privileged container
